# The Taylor expansion of the exponential of a multi-parameter group, and the derivative

Tags: derivatives, taylor-expansion, matrix-calculus

Starting from $U(t)=e^{-itH}$, I can Taylor expand around an infinitesimal transformatio as follows $U(\delta t)\approx 1-i\delta tH$.

Now, say I have a function as follows:

$$
f(x+\delta x) = ( 1-i\delta x H )f(x)
$$

I can rewrite the equation as follows:

$$
\frac{f(x+\delta x)-f(x)}{\delta x}=-iH f(x)
$$

But the left term is simply the derivative of $f(x)$ with respect to to $x$. So I obtain the definition of the derivative.

---

My question is what to do in the multi-variable case, with vectors thrown in. Consider instead the following exponential:

$$
G(x,y,t)=e^{- x \pmatrix{1&0 \\0&-1} - y \pmatrix{0&1\\1&0} - t\pmatrix{0&-1\\1&0} }
$$

We can write the matrice using the Pauli matrices and the imaginary symbol:

$$
G(x,y,t)=e^{-  \sigma_3 x - \sigma_1 y - i t}
$$

Its Taylor expansion is as follows:

$$
G(\delta x,\delta y,\delta t) \approx 1 - \sigma_3 \delta x  - \sigma_1 \delta y  - i \delta t 
$$

But unlike the previous case, it is not clear to me how I can recover the definition of some multi-variable derivative from this endeavour:

$$
h(x+\delta x,y + \delta y, t+ \delta t)-h(x,y,t)= -\sigma_3 \delta x -\sigma_1\delta y - i \delta t
$$

Is that basically a gradient-ish?

Answer (score 1):

$
\def\l{\left}
\def\r{\right}
\def\p{\partial}
\def\g#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\gg#1#2{\frac{d #1}{d #2}}
\def\m#1{ \left[\begin{array}{c}#1\end{array}\right] }
$Define block-matrix analogs of the
${\mathbb R}^{2}$ basis vectors
$$
E_1 = \l(e_1\otimes I_n\r) = \m{I_n\\0_n}
\qquad
E_2 = \l(e_2\otimes I_n\r) = \m{0_n\\I_n}
$$
Now suppose that we are given a matrix $Y\in{\mathbb R}^{n\times n}$ and an analytic function $f(z)$.

Further suppose that $Y$ is a function of a scalar parameter
$Y=Y(\alpha),\,$ then $F=f(Y)=F(\alpha)$.

Let's use the following subscript notation to denote the derivative with respect to $\alpha$
$$Y_\alpha=\gg{Y}{\alpha} \qquad F_\alpha=\gg{F}{\alpha}$$

Then, using block-triangular matrices, one can write
$$\eqalign{
X^{(\alpha)} &= \m{Y&Y_\alpha\\0&Y}, \quad
G^{(\alpha)} &= \m{F&F_\alpha\\0&F}  \;=\; f\l(X^{(\alpha)}\r) \\
}$$
One can use the $\{E_k\}$ matrices to write algebraic formulas, but they're not as concise
$$\eqalign{
X^{(\alpha)} &= E_1YE_1^T+E_2YE_2^T+E_1Y_\alpha E_2^T \\
G^{(\alpha)} &= E_1FE_1^T+E_2FE_2^T+E_1F_\alpha E_2^T \\
}$$
A better use for these matrices is to *extract* the derivative
$$\eqalign{
F_\alpha &= E_1^TG^{(\alpha)}E_2 \\
}$$
If $Y$ depends on several scalar variables,
then it has several *partial* derivatives
$$\eqalign{
&Y = Y(\alpha,\beta,\theta) \\
&Y_\alpha=\g{Y}{\alpha} \qquad
 Y_\beta=\g{Y}{\beta} \qquad
 Y_\theta=\g{Y}{\theta} \\
}$$
We can write the partial derivatives of $F=f(Y)$ with respect to these parameters as
$$\eqalign{
&X^{(\alpha)}=\m{Y&Y_\alpha\\0&Y} \qquad
&X^{(\beta)}=\m{Y&Y_\beta\\0&Y} \qquad
&X^{(\theta)}=\m{Y&Y_\theta\\0&Y} \\
&F_\alpha=E_1^Tf\!\l(X^{(\alpha)}\r)E_2 \qquad
&F_\beta=E_1^Tf\!\l(X^{(\beta)}\r)E_2 \qquad
&F_\theta=E_1^Tf\!\l(X^{(\theta)}\r)E_2 \\
}$$
and its total differential (aka first-order Taylor expansion) as
$$\eqalign{
dF &= F_\alpha\,d\alpha +F_\beta\,d\beta +F_\theta\,d\theta \\
}$$

The above derivation assumes that you have access to a robust algorithm for calculating $f(X)$.

The alternative is to use a [BCH expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula#Application_in_quantum_mechanics), but I find such calculations to be quite awkward.

That's the general case, but for the *Pauli Matrices* in your example the situation is very different. These matrices satisfy special commutator relationships such that the whole BCH expansion can be
reduced to a simple linear combination of Pauli matrices.